# How to set swfversion

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I know this seems like a silly question but how can I change the swfversion that Flash Pro sets when it builds the SWF?

I'm using a 3rd party ANA and I'm getting an error message that the SWF for that ANA is greater than my SWF when it publishes the SWF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the publish settings (File -> Publish Settings), there should be a dropdown where you can select the `Target` flash player. I'm using Flash CC and the range it allows me is 10.3 to 11.8.

Comment: It's not the flash player, it's the SWF version. The error says mine is 19 and the ANA SWF is 21.

Comment: Flash Player 11.8 is swfversion 21. If you go to C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CC\Common\Configuration\Players, you'll see an XML file for each version of the flash player. If you open up the one for 11.8, you'll see that the version is 21.

Comment: So I tried to change the player version to 21 in Air_Android_3.8.xml and in Air_Android.xml but it doesn't change. I still get the same message. I don't have an option under the publish settings to change this in the IDE for Android.

Comment: I changed the value in both AIR_Android.xml and AIR_Android_3.8.xml to 21 and restarted Flash and now it works. Thanks!